# Is there an analog for FIRST_VALUE in pandas window function?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compute a window function on a large DataFrame (several GBs).
Simplified example:

```
data_df.groupby('item_id').rolling(window='15min', on='time').agg({"item_count": 'first', "is_locked": "max"})
```

item_id - int64
time - datetime64
is_locked - boolean

I need to get first value for window in column  `item_count` but I got an error:

```
AttributeError: 'first' is not a valid function for 'RollingGroupby' object
```

But for `group by` this function exists.
I know that I can put a lambda, but since it is not a vectorized operation performance is very low. Is there a way to put `first` function *RollingGroupby*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is use custom lambda function:

```
{"item_count": lambda x: x.iat[0], "is_locked": "max"}
```

Comment: It'll work, but much slover than vectorized _min_, _max_ or even _mean_. I am looking for vectorizd version of _first_.

Comment: @MaxQwerty - I think not exist.